# UIButton not animating with UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I tried attempting to achieve the below animation using `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop`, it doesn't work and changes the image in no time. Following is the code I used:

```
[self.thanksButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame1_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[UIView  animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop animations:^{
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.thanksButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame4_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}];
```

Also tried splitting the images into four different frames and applying those images one by one using nested animation like this,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
    [self.thanksButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame2_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        [self.thanksButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame3_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
            [self.thanksButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame4_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }];
}];
```

Please let me know what needs to be fixed here. Following is the animation:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setImage cannot be animated, just by putting in it the UIView animationblock, therefore the completionBlock doesn't not wait 3 seconds, but calls immediatly. To see an actual effect set some alpha on the self.thanksbutton like  0.3,  0.5, 1 ( i don't think it will look good, but you should see the effect)

Also, I would make 2 buttons so I could use the :

```
[UIView transitionFromView:firstButton
                        toView:theOtherButton duration:0.3f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    }];
```

Comment: Thanks although there must be a native approach for it. But this did the trick for me! Thanks!